# Hibernate Query Problem

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, join, hql

I am using Hibernate. My database is as follows

A Category has many attributes

class category
contains

```
private Set <Attribute> AllAttributes= new HashSet  <Attribute>();
```

class attribute

How do I retrieve all categories together with their attributes because I am trying 'from category' but it is not working

Category Mapping File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Dec 16, 2010 8:37:02 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.Beta1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.BiddingSystem.Models.Category" table="CATEGORY">
        <id name="CategoryId" type="long">
            <column name="CATEGORYID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="CategoryName" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="CATEGORYNAME" />
        </property>

        <many-to-one name="ParentCategory" class="com.BiddingSystem.Models.Category">
            <column name="PARENT_CATEGORY_ID" />
        </many-to-one>

        <set name="SubCategory" lazy="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true">
            <key>
                <column name="PARENT_CATEGORY_ID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.BiddingSystem.Models.Category" />
        </set>

        <set name="AllAttributes" table="ATTRIBUTE" inverse="false" lazy="true"  cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="CATEGORYID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.BiddingSystem.Models.Attribute" />
        </set>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Attribute Mapping File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Dec 16, 2010 5:25:09 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.Beta1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.BiddingSystem.Models.Attribute" table="ATTRIBUTE">
        <id name="AttributeId" type="long">
            <column name="ATTRIBUTEID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="AttributeName" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="ATTRIBUTENAME" />
        </property>
        <set name="Options" table="ATTRIBUTEOPTION" inverse="false"  cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="ATTRIBUTEID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.BiddingSystem.Models.AttributeOption" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: define "not working"? What is your mapping file / your mapping annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mapped the association with `lazy="true"`. This tells hibernate that by default, a category's attributes should only be loaded from the database when they are actually accessed, in contrast to `lazy="false"` which would instruct hibernate to load the attributes whenever it loads a category. However, the directive in the mapping file affects all queries.

In case you want it only for a particular query, check out 
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins :

> A "fetch" join allows associations or
>   collections of values to be
>   initialized along with their parent
>   objects using a single select. This is
>   particularly useful in the case of a
>   collection. It effectively overrides
>   the outer join and lazy declarations
>   of the mapping file for associations
>   and collections. See Section 20.1,
>   “Fetching strategies” for more
>   information.
>
> ```
> from Cat as cat
>     inner join fetch cat.mate
>     left join fetch cat.kittens
> ```
>
> A fetch join does not usually need to
>   assign an alias, because the
>   associated objects should not be used
>   in the where clause (or any other
>   clause). The associated objects are
>   also not returned directly in the
>   query results. Instead, they may be
>   accessed via the parent object. The
>   only reason you might need an alias is
>   if you are recursively join fetching a
>   further collection:
>
> ```
> from Cat as cat
>     inner join fetch cat.mate
>     left join fetch cat.kittens child
>     left join fetch child.kittens
> ```
>
> The fetch construct cannot be used in
>   queries called using iterate() (though
>   scroll() can be used). Fetch should be
>   used together with setMaxResults() or
>   setFirstResult(), as these operations
>   are based on the result rows which
>   usually contain duplicates for eager
>   collection fetching, hence, the number
>   of rows is not what you would expect.
>   Fetch should also not be used together
>   with impromptu with condition. It is
>   possible to create a cartesian product
>   by join fetching more than one
>   collection in a query, so take care in
>   this case. Join fetching multiple
>   collection roles can produce
>   unexpected results for bag mappings,
>   so user discretion is advised when
>   formulating queries in this case.
>   Finally, note that full join fetch and
>   right join fetch are not meaningful.